printf in c do not show when i definde a 100000 size array
this is my code im trying to compile it using gcc in my console but the printf dosn't work if i put in the size more that 100000
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1000000
int main() { 
    double T1[SIZE];
    double sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        T1[i] = 1.0;
        sum += T1[i];
    }
    printf("la somme est : %6.f\n",sum);
    return 0; 
} 

result
PS C:\Users\Mahdi\Documents\openmp> gcc -o c -fopenmp c.c
PS C:\Users\Mahdi\Documents\openmp> .\c
PS C:\Users\Mahdi\Documents\openmp> 

#define SIZE 1000 (less is shown)

A million doubles would need 8 MB of storage. On a typical Linux system the stack only gets 1 MB (unless expressly asked for more).
